# How to access value from a QML combo box which is fetching values from table/model?

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a combobox which gets value from a table. I get the combobox object using:

```
QObject * object=engine->rootObjects().at(0)->findChild<QObject* >("comboobjectname");
```

Now, how do I set a value from the combobox list and set it on GUI using C++?

Comment: Is the model implemented in C++ or QML?

Comment: Model implemented using C++

Answer (score 2):

I always recommend the same: update your GUI using the model if you have one.

I don't know your whole project, but if you have the model in C++, you should have a class with methods to add, remove and get data.

In this example, I'm going to show you a very simple model, `Animal`, with two values: type and size.

**animal.h**

```
#ifndef ANIMAL_H
#define ANIMAL_H

#include <QString>

class Animal
{
public:
    Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size);

    QString type() const;
    QString size() const;

private:
    QString m_type;
    QString m_size;
};

#endif // ANIMAL_H
```

**animal.cpp**

```
#include "animal.h"

Animal::Animal(const QString &type, const QString &size)
    : m_type(type), m_size(size)
{
}

QString Animal::type() const
{
    return m_type;
}

QString Animal::size() const
{
    return m_size;
}
```

**animalmodel.h**

```
#ifndef ANIMALMODEL_H
#define ANIMALMODEL_H

#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QStringList>
#include "animal.h"

class AnimalModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    enum AnimalRoles {
        TypeRole = Qt::UserRole + 1,
        SizeRole
    };

    AnimalModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE void addAnimal(const QString &type, const QString &size);

    void addAnimal(const Animal &animal);

    Q_INVOKABLE void removeAnimal(int row);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const;

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;

protected:
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
private:
    QList<Animal> m_animals;
};

#endif // ANIMALMODEL_H
```

**animalmodel.cpp**

```
#include "animalmodel.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QListIterator>

AnimalModel::AnimalModel(QObject *parent)
    : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

void AnimalModel::addAnimal(const QString &type, const QString &size)
{
    addAnimal(Animal(type, size));
}

void AnimalModel::addAnimal(const Animal &animal)
{
    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), rowCount(), rowCount());
    m_animals << animal;
    endInsertRows();
}

void AnimalModel::removeAnimal(int row)
{
    beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row);
    m_animals.removeAt(row);
    removeRow(row, QModelIndex());
    endRemoveRows();
}

int AnimalModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent) const {
    Q_UNUSED(parent);
    return m_animals.count();
}

QVariant AnimalModel::data(const QModelIndex & index, int role) const {
    if (index.row() < 0 || index.row() >= m_animals.count())
        return QVariant();

    const Animal &animal = m_animals[index.row()];
    if (role == TypeRole)
        return animal.type();
    else if (role == SizeRole)
        return animal.size();
    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> AnimalModel::roleNames() const {
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;
    roles[TypeRole] = "type";
    roles[SizeRole] = "size";
    return roles;
}
```

Thanks to this model, we can use it in QML to show, for example, a `TableView` and a `ComboBox`:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 1.4
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("")

    toolBar: ToolBar {
        id: toolbar
        width: parent.width

        style: ToolBarStyle {
            padding {
                left: 20
                right: 20
                top: 15
                bottom: 15
            }
            background: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 100
                implicitHeight: 40
                border.color: "#999"
                gradient: Gradient {
                    GradientStop { position: 0 ; color: "#fff" }
                    GradientStop { position: 1 ; color: "#aaa" }
                }
            }
        }
        ColumnLayout{
            spacing: 2
            RowLayout {
                Button {
                    id: addButton
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                    text: "Add item"

                    onClicked: {
                        if (typeBox.text || sizeBox.text) {
                            myModel.addAnimal(typeBox.text, sizeBox.text)
                        }
                    }
                }
                TextField {
                    id: typeBox
                    placeholderText: "type"

                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.left: addButton.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                }

                TextField {
                    id: sizeBox
                    placeholderText: "size"

                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    anchors.left: typeBox.right
                    anchors.leftMargin: 5
                }
            }

            RowLayout {
                Button {
                    id: deleteButton
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                    text: "Delete item"

                    onClicked: {
                        if(tableView.currentRow != -1)
                        {
                            myModel.removeAnimal(tableView.currentRow)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            ColumnLayout{
                spacing: 2
                RowLayout {
                    ComboBox {
                        id: myCombobox
                        currentIndex: 2
                        model: myModel
                        textRole : "type"
                    }

                    Button {
                        id: printvaluesButton
                        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter

                        text: "Print values"

                        onClicked: {
                            console.debug(myCombobox.currentIndex)
                            comboboxManagement.printValues(myModel,
                                                           myModel.index(myCombobox.currentIndex, 0))
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    TableView {
        id: tableView

        frameVisible: false
        sortIndicatorVisible: true

        anchors.fill: parent

        Layout.minimumWidth: 400
        Layout.minimumHeight: 240
        Layout.preferredWidth: 600
        Layout.preferredHeight: 400

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "type"
            title: "Type"
            width: 100
        }

        TableViewColumn {
            role: "size"
            title: "Size"
            width: 200
        }

        model: myModel
    }
}
```

As you can see, we have some buttons to add and remove items. When a button is clicked, both `TableView` and `ComboBox` are updated.

In the particular case of our `ComboBox`, we have a C++ class to print the selected element. To have or not a class like this to perform these kind of tasks is up to you and depends on your requirements.

**comboboxmanagement.h**

```
#ifndef COMBOBOXMANAGEMENT_H
#define COMBOBOXMANAGEMENT_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>
#include "animalmodel.h"

class ComboboxManagement : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ComboboxManagement(QObject *parent = 0);

    Q_INVOKABLE bool printValues(AnimalModel* model,
                               const QModelIndex &modelIndex);

};

#endif // COMBOBOXMANAGEMENT_H
```

**comboboxmanagement.cpp**

```
#include "comboboxmanagement.h"

ComboboxManagement::ComboboxManagement(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

bool ComboboxManagement::printValues(AnimalModel* model,
                       const QModelIndex &modelIndex) {
    qDebug() << model->data(modelIndex, AnimalModel::TypeRole);
    return true;
}
```

Finally, the `main.cpp`

```
#include "animalmodel.h"
#include "comboboxmanagement.h"

#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include <qqmlcontext.h>
#include <qqml.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickitem.h>
#include <QtQuick/qquickview.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    AnimalModel model;
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Wolf", "Medium"));
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Polar bear", "Large"));
    model.addAnimal(Animal("Quoll", "Small"));

    ComboboxManagement comboboxManagement;
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

    QQmlContext *ctxt = engine.rootContext();
    ctxt->setContextProperty("myModel", &model);    
    ctxt->setContextProperty("comboboxManagement", &comboboxManagement);

    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/view.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```